# Bootstrap 3 Snippets in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am using visual studio code, when call any bs3 snipper , it creates extra top and bottom empty line.
Someone please show me how can I prevent that?

[image]

green line are one I want to remove automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to edit the bootstrap-3 snippet file `snippets.json` under the following path `C:\Users\<Username>\.vscode\extensions\wcwhitehead.bootstrap-3-snippets-0.1.0\snippets` and remove first and last `\n`  from each snippet as below example (restatr VS Code after update).

Original snippet:

```
 "bs3-alert:danger": {
        "prefix": "bs3-alert:danger",
        "body": "\n<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">\n\t<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>\n\t<strong>${1:Title!}</strong> ${2:Alert body ...}\n</div>\n",
        "description": "Danger Alert Box",
        "scope": ""
 },
```

Updated snippet:

```
"bs3-alert:danger": {
        "prefix": "bs3-alert:danger",
        "body": "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">\n\t<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>\n\t<strong>${1:Title!}</strong> ${2:Alert body ...}\n</div>",
        "description": "Danger Alert Box",
        "scope": ""
 },
```

Comment: This means I have to modify every snippet. That is impossible :(

Comment: You can modify it in an easy way by search and replace using any editor by replacing `"\n` the up line with `"` and `\n"` the bottom line with `"`.